# how to get log lines written to a file within the last 5 minutes?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have a log file like the following, the log is continuously logged:

```
2021-08-12 16:09:17 textsp sdgg
reponse:success
prams:invalid
2021-08-12 16:10:17 textdfdfdlfs sfdfs
reponse: failed
prams:valid
```

I want to write a script to get the log since 5 minutes ago. But I still have no idea, Lines contain reponse parameter, prams don't have time so it's difficult to filter. Do you have any ideas for this case?

Comment: Do you want the log lines that were added  *within* the last 5 minutes? Or only the one added *exactly* 5 minutes ago (to the exact second?) or were added *over* 5 minutes ago?

Comment: I want the log lines added within the last 5 minutes

Comment: Thank you very much @StéphaneChazelas, I tried to follow the way you instructed me and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `date` and `awk`, you could do:

```
START=$(date -d '5 minutes ago' +'%F %T') \
  LC_ALL=C awk '
    /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/ && $0 >= ENVIRON["START"], 0
    ' < file.log
```

Which uses `awk 'start, end {action}'` to run action for lines in the start, end range, but here with no action specified which defaults to printing the line, 0 (meaning *false*) as the end condition, and starting on the first line that starts with something that looks like a timestamp and is greater than the timestamp for 5 minutes ago.

For the logs between two timestamps:

```
START=$(date -d '15 minutes ago' +'%F %T') \
  END=$(date -d  '5 minutes ago' +'%F %T') \
  LC_ALL=C awk '
    match($0, /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}/) {
      timestamp = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
      if (timestamp > ENVIRON["END"]) exit
      if (timestamp >= ENVIRON["START"])
        started = 1
    }
    started' < file.log
```

Those assume the log entries are in chronological order. That's not always the case, like when the timestamp refers to the start of an action but the log entry is added at the end of the action and several actions are performed concurrently with some server software.